# How to get max from first row to current row

Tags: excel

I have a val column as below,how to get max value from first row
i.e for row-1 max value is 1  and for row-3 max value form row-1 to row-2
and for last row max value row 1-4 is 8

```
   val  roll_Max
     1   1
     4   4
     3   4
     8   4
     6   8
```

Comment: Your example is inconsistent. In second row the result is 4, so you include the value next to it, but in fourth row is still 4, however the value next to it is 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The roll_max is a rolling maximum field then right? So in your example enter in cell b2 the formula:

```
=MAX($A$2:A2)
```

And drag this down so that the cell b3 contains `=MAX($A$2:A3)` etc.

Comment: Thanks tdsymonds, It is taking lot of time for large number of rows , any efficient way to do that

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution, check which one is faster. The cell above will contain the maximum value, so there is no need to check max for all cells again. Just check if the new value is bigger than the last max.

In B2 insert `=A2`.

In B3 insert `=MAX(A3,B2)` and drag to the end.